# android jsonObject throws exception

Tags: android, json, parsing

My code:

```
string result = "[{"lat":"b", "lon":"d", "ulica":"ulica1"}]";
jArray = new JSONArray(result);
tab =new String[jArray.length()];
json = jArray.getJSONObject(0);

tab[0]=json.getString("lat");
tab[1]=json.getString("lon");  
tab[2]=json.getString("ulica");
```

it throws jsonException, no value for lon.  Can anyone help me?

It was my mistake instead of lon I had lot in my result string... I was looking for this misspelling from early morning .... ;P

Comment: Can you post the message in the exception please?

Comment: What exact error message you are getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must escape " with \" so instead of "a" you need to have \"a\"

Answer (score 0):

I think these lines are the problem:

> tab[0]=json.getString("lat");
>   tab[1]=json.getString("lon");
>   tab[2]=json.getString("ulica");

'lat', 'lon' and 'ulica' aren't mentioned in the JSON, so they won't be found. Try this:

> tab[0]=json.getString("a");
>   tab[1]=json.getString("c");

Then you may get 'b' and 'd' respectively.

Note this is untested.

Answer (score 0):

jArray.length() is  actualy 1, so there was another(outOfRangeException) mistake.